# Проблемы с URL-manager

Tags: php, url, yii2

Прописал правила вот так

```
'urlManager'=>[
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '/admin'=>'/tree/admin',
        ],
```

Пытаюсь обратиться по адресу http://localhost/admin - работает, http://localhost/admin/- нет!
натыкался на такую статью мол это нормально, но все же, можно как то спасти ситуацию?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятым

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Пробовать применить регулярное выражение и конкретно знак `?` означающее число повторений Ноль или одно.

```
urlManager'=>[ 
    'showScriptName' => false, 
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 
    'rules' => [ 
        '<action:(admin)\/?>' => 'tree/<action>',
    ],
```

В правилах (rules) менеджера (urlmanager) фреймворка регулярное выражение действует если оно написано в теге вида `<TAG_NAME:REGULAR_EXPRESSION>`,
где

`TAG_NAME` - название тега

`REGULAR_EXPRESSION` - регулярное выражение

Подробнее можно почитать [Здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md)

Comment: лучший , спасибо большое, релаьно помогло!

Comment: @Анатолий  Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)